# How to create result table with vlookup from merged cells

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have this data table and i want another result table. when I write name of state ,result table can show all of company with data1,data2 and data3.I trying use vlookup but because there are merged cells the formula just show first row.
how can I fix problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? Maybe by adding a screenshot, or an example with dummy values perhaps?

Comment: I uploaded screenshot here:http://postimg.org/image/96vdzypg7/

Comment: This is my table and I trying to reach result from it. but because merged cells it just show the first row

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/518bghysv/ is this one helpful? Also I trying use filter! but it is not good for my boss!

Comment: Do you also want to use filter? It will be difficult with so many merged cells :(

Comment: You can't use AutoFilter on merged cells.

Comment: filter is not good and nice work! even I don't have enough knowledge for VB programming

Comment: You want to be able to, for example, type Alaska as the lookup value and get back company2, company3, company4 plus all the data for each company?

Comment: Thanks my friends.the problem solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to set up a lookup range so that when you enter a particular state, you can see the data for all the companies that have data in that state. Here is one way to do that.

The first thing you would need to do is set up three columns to the left of the original table:

- The first column holds the name of the state associated with each row of data
- The second is an index that counts off the number of data rows in each state
- The third combines the first two columns to produce a unique key value for each row in the table.

All the values in these three columns can be assigned by formula. The picture below shows the formulas for the first row of cells `A9:C9`, which are then copied down through row 27.

[image: columns for lookup key]

The next step is to lay out the new table, which is in cells `Q8:U27` in my example.

There are several thing to note about the setup. First, the state that will be displayed is entered in cell `Q9`, which I've highlighted in yellow. To the left of the table, in column P, I've entered item numbers from 1 to 19, which will be needed to construct the key values for the lookups. The lookup formulas themselves are in cells `R9:U27`; in the picture, the formulas for the first row (`R9:U9`) are shown (they are then copied down through row 27).

[image: new table]

It's worth taking a moment to look more closely at one of the lookups. Here is the formula for the first company name in cell `R9'.

```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($Q$9&$P9,$C$9:$N$27,4,0),"")
```

Looking at each of the arguments of the `VLOOKUP` in turn, `$Q$9&$P9` concatenates the state name in cell `Q9` with the item number (1 in this case), yielding the lookup value 'California1'. The lookup table is defined as the range `$C$9:$N$27` - column C of that range is what the lookup value is matched against. The third argument is the column from which to return a value if the lookup is a match. The number 4 here corresponds with the company name column of the original table. Finally, the last argument is 0 (or equivalently, FALSE) indicating an exact match is required.

Finally, the `VLOOKUP` function is wrapped inside `IFERROR`. This catches the `#N/A` that would otherwise be returned when no match is found, replacing it with an empty string ("").

Comment: I guess that's what the OP was looking for :)