# Excel Vlookup with a merged cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to run vlookup on the merged cells in (A2-A4), (A5-A7), (A8-A10) against E2, E3, E4. 
Where there is an exact match, I need to populate the (F) values in (B)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create result table with vlookup from merged cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740523/how-to-create-result-table-with-vlookup-from-merged-cells)

Answer (score 0):

Under result in B2 you can write the following:

`=IF(OFFSET($A2,0,0)=0,B1,VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$4,2,FALSE))`

$A2 is the first merged cell
B1 is the header it will change to the corresponding result which you need to repeat
$E$2:$F$4 is the Lookup array change the reference to correspond to all your Lookup Array and keep $ for absolute references to be fix
Whenever the Offset find a Value it will return the Vlookup result
You can drag the formula down

Answer (score 0):

In B2 as,

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("ZZZ", A$1:A2)), E:F, 2, FALSE)
```

If *January* is actually *1/1/2017* formatted as *mmmm* then use,

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1e99, A$1:A2)), E:F, 2, FALSE)
```

[image]